# How to know if backup file is available before trying to restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent

I have a restore job, but i want to add a step before restore step to know if backup file available.so that it should go to restore step only if backup file available.Please let me know a query which i can use before restoration step

Comment: You are taking restore process through TSQL or Maintenance Plan. Could you tell elaborate.

Comment: I already have a scheduled restoration job, but i want to add a step before restore step to check if backup file available and to go to step 2 only if there is backup file available. @MdHaidarAliKhan

Comment: Are you saying the backup step is in the same job as the restore step?  If that is the case, you should be able to use the advanced section of the backup step to go to the restore step 'on success' of the backup step.  If your restore step is in a completely separate job from the backup, then how is the restore step trying to determine 'which' backup to restore,  Only successful backups would be cataloged in the msdb backup tables.  Make sure your backup jobs have 'Notifications' being sent on failures.

Comment: I have 2 different jobs for backup and restore, But i want to check if backup file (.bak) available in particular location mentioned in restoration job, before it start restoring database @ScottHodgin

Answer (score 3):

I've found an answer on SO that could help you:

[**Check for file exists or not in sql server?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740000/check-for-file-exists-or-not-in-sql-server)

Using this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_FileExists(@path varchar(512))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @result INT
     EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path, @result OUTPUT
     RETURN cast(@result as bit)
END;
GO
```

You could check if the backup file exists before to restore it.

Answer (score 1):

On your restore job, create STEP 1 that will run a VERIFYONLY (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/113/checking-to-make-sure-a-sql-server-backup-is-useable/).  On Success, run the actual restore in STEP2

Comment: The backup file could be very big and verifying it might take time. If the goal is merely to make sure the file exists, then perhaps RESTORE HEADERONLY would do better, although in the OP's scenario (checking the file before actually restoring it) VERIFYONLY may indeed be more relevant.

Comment: @Andriy M - agreed - it's up to the OP to decide how much verification to perform before attempting the restore.

Comment: Yup, I just thought we could give the OP another option (which didn't seem to me worth a separate answer as it's based on your suggestion; feel free to incorporate it into your answer, by the way, and to flag the comments as obsolete afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

As pinal Dave blog [Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/02/25/sql-server-restore-database-backup-using-sql-script-t-sql/) if you want SQL SERVER – Restore Database Backup using SQL Script through (T-SQL). Then the steps is as follows:

```
Step 1: Retrive the Logical file name of the database from backup.
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = 'D:\BackUpYourBaackUpFile.bak'
GO


Step 2: Use the values in the LogicalName Column in following Step.


---Make Database to single user Mode
ALTER DATABASE YourDB
SET SINGLE_USER WITH
ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

----Restore Database
RESTORE DATABASE YourDB
FROM DISK = 'D:\BackUpYourBaackUpFile.bak'
WITH MOVE 'YourMDFLogicalName' TO 'D:\DataYourMDFFile.mdf',
MOVE 'YourLDFLogicalName' TO 'D:\DataYourLDFFile.ldf'

/*If there is no error in statement before database will be in multiuser
mode.
If error occurs please execute following command it will convert
database in multi user.*/
ALTER DATABASE YourDB SET MULTI_USER
GO
```

Comment: OP is asking how to check whether .bak file exists or not and depending on that perform a restore. what you are showing is logical name of file

Comment: Yes you are right @Shanky.That's exactly what i want..Please help me in that

Comment: Give me some time, I will test script and get back to you. You basically have to use `Master.dbo.xp_fileexist` in IF clause and if above returns true execute restore else print that file does not exists

Comment: Ok @Shanky  ,Thanks alot...waiting for the script..

Comment: @Shanky did u tried your script